# Why does steering wheel shudder when applying brake?

Tags: honda, brakes, civic, steering, steering-wheel

I'm driving honda civic 2009, with new tires, new tie rods, new brake rotors, new brake pads, wheel balancing is also done. When applying brake, at speed of 40km/hr or above, the steering wheel shudders. What could be the issue?

Note that the steering wheel shudders only when I try to apply brake. And not otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Was this shudder happening before you had this work done, or started after?

Comment: Was hapenning before also. Hence mechanic advsied to change couple of parts as mentioned in the question. Now the mechanic thinks that struts may need to be replaced, but I dont know whether to trust him

Comment: Assuming that the tie rods, brake, and wheel balancing were done properly, there is bent wheel, out of round tire, worn wheel bearing, ball joints, as well as the struts.  I'm not a big fan of "replace and hope", perhaps a trip to a different mechanic who has more skill is in order.

Comment: Can a good mechanic understand whether the changed parts like tie rod, rotor, are in good condition or not?

Answer (score 1):

The most common thing is a warped rotor. Even though it's new doesn't mean it's not warped. Sometimes an inferior quality rotor can be warped out of the box. Rotors can also become warped quickly by sticking calipers and\or slides or bad brake hoses. These can cause the rotors to overheat and warp in short order. If hub is excessively dirty it can also cause problems. Also over torquing the lug nuts can warp the rotor. I think if you checked the run-out on your rotors you will find one or more rotors well over .002" out. This can also be caused by a loose caliper mounting bolt or a loose bracket bolt.

Comment: Many times, new rotors will be warped if they’re stacked too high in the warehouse.

Comment: Is it safe to drive like this?

Comment: It depends on what is actually causing the vibration. Until you find out what the problem is it may be very dangerous to drive.