# On uneven road, I hear sound from front left side as though the tire is touching the fender and rubbing against it for a second

Tags: honda, civic, suspension, shock-absorber, struts

On uneven road, and also on speed braker, at low speed of 1 to 10 km/hr, I hear sound from front right side of bonet. It sounds as though the tire is touching the fender and rubbing against it (it is not a metal sound, it is not a thud, it is not a clunk). I checked and confirm that the tire is not touching the fender.

Its the honda civic 2009 model, done around 70000miles.

I have got new tie rods, brake rotors, pads, tires installed. The struts are old. What could be issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does steering wheel shudder when applying brake?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/73565/why-does-steering-wheel-shudder-when-applying-brake)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your other question:  https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/73565/why-does-steering-wheel-shudder-when-applying-brake

Comment: Hi no its not duplicate question. They are separate issues.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check if its actual wheel rubbing is to get a flashlight and look all inside the wheel well and on the tire surface (mostly near the corners) for linear striping marks. Shouldn't be too hard to spot. If it's too dirty to see any marks, you can also try dusting the inside of the wheel well with something like foot powder to make any rubbing more visible (just an idea, not something I've tried, and conditions could certainly make this a non-workable technique).

As a real answer to the question, I'd advise that you read jwh20's comment on your other post. Yes, struts **could** be the cause, but there are *many* components to the front-end suspension system that could cause these kind of issues. Try to find the best mechanic in your area and have them look at it. It could be something cheaper than struts, and it could need more than one thing.

I'd also advise trying to recall when the issues started happening (the wheel shuddering and rubbing sounds). They could be interrelated, and something like hitting a pothole, or even gently rubbing a curb could have caused damage. If there was some particular event, that may help greatly with the diagnostic process (either online or in a shop).

Comment: Ok so you mean a good mechanic can look at the problem and pin point at the cause?

Comment: @variable yes. Maybe not exactly, but suspension and steering are somewhat picky. So a component and be damaged, but not necessarily obviously so. A good mechanic, that really understands the system, will be best able to determine the exact cause. Like I said though, there could be more than one thing, depending on what happened. If you can have the mechanic do a test drive and reproduce the issue(s) that's most ideal. Try to keep your own diagnosis out of it though. Just tell them what's going on, show them if possible, and let them figure it out. The hard part is finding someone really good.